# FMX: How to draw a bitmap with reduced size and high quality?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I notice that quality of images is poor when drawn smaller than the source image. This is especially obvious when the image contains thin lines as the subsampling causes parts of the lines to disappear. I'm looking for a way to improve the quality without compromising too much on runtime. So ideally I'd like it to be done on the GPU. Below is an example with 3 different methods. The last method is my own code, which shows what I'm trying to achieve but is not done on the GPU and so is too slow. It also won't work if I want to include some rotation as well as scale. I have also tried changing the HighSpeed flag in the DrawBitmap function, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

[image]

Form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 240
  ClientWidth = 438
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Image1: TImage
    MultiResBitmap = <
      item
      end>
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
  end
  object Image2: TImage
    MultiResBitmap = <
      item
      end>
    Position.X = 216.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
  end
  object Image3: TImage
    MultiResBitmap = <
      item
      end>
    Position.X = 216.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 80.000000000000000000
  end
  object Image4: TImage
    MultiResBitmap = <
      item
      end>
    Position.X = 216.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 152.000000000000000000
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 266.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 164.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Scale destination rectangle'
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Position.X = 266.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 96.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 164.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Create canvas scale transform'
    TabOrder = 5
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Position.X = 266.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 168.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 164.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Hand coded Shrink function'
    TabOrder = 4
  end
end
```

Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  PAlphaColorArray = ^TAlphaColorArray;
  TAlphaColorArray = array[0..32767] of TAlphaColor;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;
    Image3: TImage;
    Image4: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure Shrink(const ABitmap : TBitmap ; out ABitmapOut : TBitmap);

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Math, Math.Vectors;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  r : Single = 0.2;
  size : Integer = 200;
var
  srcRect, dstRect : TRectF;
  bmp : TBitmap;
begin
  // Create source image - circle
  Image1.Bitmap.BitmapScale := 1;
  Image1.Bitmap.SetSize(size, size);
  Image1.Width := Image1.Bitmap.Width;
  Image1.Height := Image1.Bitmap.Height;
  if Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then begin
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Clear(TAlphaColorRec.White);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawEllipse(TRectF.Create(size/10,size/10,9*size/10,9*size/10), 1);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

  srcRect := Image1.Bitmap.BoundsF;
  dstRect := srcRect;
  dstRect.BottomRight := PointF(dstRect.Width*r, dstRect.Height*r);

  // Try reducing by scaling the destination rectangle
  // Same method as TBitmap.CreateThumbnail
  Image2.Bitmap.BitmapScale := 1;
  Image2.Bitmap.SetSize(Ceil(dstRect.Width), Ceil(dstRect.Height));
  Image2.Width := Image2.Bitmap.Width;
  Image2.Height := Image2.Bitmap.Height;
  if Image2.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then begin
    Image2.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, 1, True);
    Image2.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

  // Try reducing using the canvas transform matrix
  Image3.Bitmap.BitmapScale := 1;
  Image3.Bitmap.SetSize(Ceil(dstRect.Width), Ceil(dstRect.Height));
  Image3.Width := Image2.Bitmap.Width;
  Image3.Height := Image2.Bitmap.Height;
  if Image3.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then begin
    Image3.Bitmap.Canvas.SetMatrix(TMatrix.CreateScaling(r, r));
    Image3.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, srcRect, srcRect, 1, True);
    Image3.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

  // Reduce using Shrink function - Slow (not done on GPU)
  bmp := TBitmap.Create(Ceil(dstRect.Width), Ceil(dstRect.Height));
  bmp.BitmapScale := 1;
  Image4.Width := bmp.Width;
  Image4.Height := bmp.Height;
  Shrink(Image1.Bitmap, bmp);
  Image4.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);
  bmp.Free;
end;

// Shrink a bitmap using all available data from source
// Could be sped up a little for specific cases such as scaling by 0.5
procedure Shrink(const ABitmap : TBitmap ; out ABitmapOut : TBitmap);
Var
  Lx, Ly : integer;
  LyBox, LxBox, LyBox1, LyBox2, LxBox1, LxBox2 : integer;
  TR, TG, TB, TA : integer;
  LRowIn, LRowOut, LRowInStart : PAlphaColorArray;
  LBoxCount : integer;
  LRowBytes, LRowBytesIn : integer;
  LBoxRows : array of PAlphaColorArray;
  LRatioW, LRatioH : Real;
  bdata, bdatao : TBitmapData;
begin
  if (ABitmapOut.Width = 0) or (ABitmapOut.Height = 0) then Exit;

  LRatioH := ABitmap.Height / ABitmapOut.Height;
  LRatioW := ABitmap.Width / ABitmapOut.Width;

  ABitmap.Map(TMapAccess.Read, bdata);
  ABitmapOut.Map(TMapAccess.Write, bdatao);

  try
    SetLength(LBoxRows, Trunc(LRatioH)+1);

    LRowOut := PAlphaColorArray(bdatao.GetScanline(0));
    LRowBytes := bdatao.Pitch;
    LRowBytesIn := bdata.Pitch;
    LRowInStart := PAlphaColorArray(bdata.GetScanline(0));

    for Ly := 0 to ABitmapOut.Height-1 do begin

      LyBox1 := Trunc(Ly*LRatioH);
      LyBox2 := Trunc((Ly+1)*LRatioH) - 1;

      for LyBox := LyBox1 to LyBox2 do
        PByte(LBoxRows[LyBox-LyBox1]) := PByte(LRowInStart) + LyBox*LRowBytesIn;

      for Lx := 0 to ABitmapOut.Width-1 do begin

        LxBox1 := Trunc(Lx*LRatioW);
        LxBox2 := Trunc((Lx+1)*LRatioW) - 1;

        TR := 0; TG := 0; TB := 0; TA := 0;
        LBoxCount := 0;
        for LyBox := LyBox1 to LyBox2 do begin
          LRowIn := LBoxRows[LyBox-LyBox1];
          for LxBox := LxBox1 to LxBox2 do begin
            Inc(TB, TAlphaColorRec(LRowIn[LxBox]).B);
            Inc(TG, TAlphaColorRec(LRowIn[LxBox]).G);
            Inc(TR, TAlphaColorRec(LRowIn[LxBox]).R);
            Inc(TA, TAlphaColorRec(LRowIn[LxBox]).A);
            Inc(LBoxCount);
          end;
        end;

        TAlphaColorRec(LRowOut[Lx]).B := TB div LBoxCount;
        TAlphaColorRec(LRowOut[Lx]).G := TG div LBoxCount;
        TAlphaColorRec(LRowOut[Lx]).R := TR div LBoxCount;
        TAlphaColorRec(LRowOut[Lx]).A := TA div LBoxCount;

      end;

      Inc(PByte(LRowOut), LRowBytes);

    end;

  finally
    ABitmap.Unmap(bdata);
    ABitmapOut.Unmap(bdatao);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Have you considered using SVG images and components?

Comment: @Delphi Coder. Thanks, but my app is already mostly using vector type graphics. It still allows users to load images and move them around, which is where I have this issue. I see that Inkscape reduces imported images with much higher quality, so maybe I'll have a look how it's doing it.

Comment: You can also have a look the lib ``Graphics32``

Comment: When the scale factor is greater than two (both upscaling and downscaling), several pixels are ignored, this is normal and expected, not something exclusive to Delphi. What image editors do is do progressive downscaling (or upscaling) at 2x scale and the last at the remaining scale (less than 2x).